# onClick in button tag is not working in react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, buttonclick

hi i am a newbie in react i am facing a issue in classbased component
given below is my component which i am calling inside another component of react i just want to call the temp function when onClick gets fired but in my case it is not working please let me know where i am doing wrong?

```
import react from 'react'
import '../../../css/classBased/editor/textFieldForEditor.css'
import addTextField from './leftTrayIconsForEditor'
class TextField extends react.Component {
    
    temp() {
        console.log('hi there')
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='textfield_parent_container'>
          <div>
          <center>
          <div>
          <button onClick={()=> {this.temp()}}>
          <i className="material-icons md-18">article</i>
          </button>
          <button>
          <i className="material-icons md-18">image</i>
          </button>
          <button>
          <i className="material-icons md-18">movie</i>
          </button>
          </div>
          </center>
          </div>
          <textarea className='text' id={`textfield${this.props.widgetNumber}`}></textarea>
          <div className='utilitytrayouter'>
          <center>
          <div className='temp'>
          <button>
          <i className="material-icons md-18">article</i>
          </button>
          <button>
          <i className="material-icons md-18">image</i>
          </button>
          <button>
          <i className="material-icons md-18">movie</i>
          </button>
          </div>
          </center>
          </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
export default TextField;
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get an error? What's the output to the console?

Comment: @RonB. when i am clicking on element where this event is attached then nothing is showing in console also it is not throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

It actually [works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dacauh) and clicking the first `article` button really calls `console.log('hi there')`. Proving the error message could be helpful.

But since you are using `Class` components most likely you are facing the [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) "problem" and what you need is to `bind` your `temp` method to `TextField` component. The easiest way (but may require a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) depending on your setup) is by using the arrow function:

```
temp = () => {console.log('hi there')}
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: can you tell me how to bind this method?